# How can I evaluate $ \int{\sqrt{1-k \cos{x}} dx} $?

Tags: calculus, analysis, indefinite-integrals

When $ k = 1 $ the solution is simple to find. But how can I do when $ k \neq 1 $? With the aid of WolframAlpha I realized that this primitive involves the E elliptic integral (i.e. second kind), but how can I reduce my problem to this?
Thanks.

Comment: With the [Weierstrass's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) you can rationalize the trigonometrix part. You end up with an integral of [the right form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: this leads to a elliptic function

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy thanks for your reply.
I have a last little doubt. Let $ 0 \leq k < 1 $.
I have obtained: $ \sqrt{1-k} \int{\sqrt{1-\frac{2k}{k-1} (\sin{\frac{x}{2}})^2} dx} $.
The question is that the fraction $ \frac{2k}{k-1} $ is negative, and it is a problem in order to use the elliptic integral. How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of "evaluation" do you need? Series expansion of the primitive function? Or is the ultimate goal to compute definite integrals? They were saying [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Notational_variants) that the people at Wolfram defined their $K$ in terms of that coefficient, instead of assuming it positive and defining it in terms of its square root. So, for numerical evaluations you can use them. The functions seems to be called *EllipticK[m]*.

Comment: My goal is to compute definite integrals. My only doubt is that "formally" - in the definition of elliptic integrals - the paralmeter $ m $, the modulus $ k $, and the modular angle $ \alpha $ _must_ be non-negative (I have used the definitions and notations like in [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Argument_notation)). On the other side, I tried on Wolfram to compute my elliptic integral and it works, although the parameter is negative.